# Is there any way to refresh data by a flag or something?

Tags: reactjs

I am using RTK reduxjs/toolkit, so far my function to fetch data is working good, but now i will need to update all of Articles if i create a new Article, i was reading the documentation i think i will need a flag `skip` or `refetchOnMountOrArgChange`

This is the doc https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi

This is my code

```
const { data } = useGetArticlesQuery({}, { skip: true })
```

so that i am creating this state

```
 const [skip, setSkip] = useState(false)
```

if i set as true then i get error of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by Providing tags and then Invalidating it.

[Automated Re-fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching)

Provide:

```
getPosts: build.query<Post[], void>({
      query: () => '/posts',
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) =>
        result
          ? [...result.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Post' as const, id })), 'Post']
          : ['Post'],
    }),
```

Invalidate:

```
addPost: build.mutation<Post, Omit<Post, 'id'>>({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: 'post',
        method: 'POST',
        body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Post'],
    }),
```